# Can't send mails using contact plugin

Tags: plugins, email, plugin-contact-form-7

There are many contact form plugins available but none of them succeeds in sending mail even contact 7 form. Only the default contact form of Jetpack wordpress succeeds in sending the mail. But the problem is it only sends the mail when I use the email id which I used while signing for the wordpress, a gmail id. if i replace that gmail id with my website support email id in my user profile, even the jetpack coontact form fails. I want to use my website email id as it has auto-responder facility.

Answer (score 2):

Cheers.
When sending mail, how does it fail? Does everything look normal on the frontend (no error messages or so), but the mail do not arrive at their destination?

If so, maybe you need to set up SMTP. With Gmail and some other services you need to send with SMTP instead of PHP Mail (when sending, you got no visual feedback that the mail could not be delivered). I use http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smtp/ for this. Google Apps or Gmail-accounts are pretty common, so this is a easy way to fix the problem.

Else, see if you can come up with more details (if you got access to your logs, maybe you could find some clues).

Comment: @"Christopher Anderton"  Actually, no error is displayed, I simply don't receive the message

Comment: Most of this answer would be better as a comment, can you edit out your questions and put them as comments and distill your response down to your answer of SMTP/Gmail?